# Need Regular Expression pattern in VB

Tags: regex, vb.net, qtp

I am new to this, what is the Regular Expression pattern for **10: 26 AM** in VB, not up to the time, need pattern for fixed time. Please help on this.

Comment: I don't get it. Please specify sample input and desired output.

Comment: what patterns have you tried?

Comment: please clarify your question as it's too vague

Comment: Are you are asking for the VB *Format String*, like `Date.ToString("hh:mm tt")`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For programming questions in general, you really need to be precise with your requirements.  This holds especially true for regex questions - you really need to state exactly what you need, and it really helps to provide specific examples that should match and ones that should not match, and make clear any oddities  that someone not in your shoes might misunderstand or miss (eg in this case - is the space after your colon intentional or a typing error?).  Stating what you've tried will help show you're actually trying to solve this yourself, not just looking for handouts.

Answer (score 3):

All strings *are* also valid regular expressions (once you’ve escaped any characters that have a special meaning in the regex dialect you’re using). So if you want to search for a fixed string using regular expressions, just use that fixed string.

In particular, your fixed-time input doesn’t contain any special characters so we don’t even need to escape it:

```
"10: 26 AM"
```

Seriously, that’s it. It’s a valid regular expression that matches exactly your string, and nothing else. *However*, if you’re just going to match a fixed string you don’t need to use regular expressions at all, and using a normal string search might be slightly faster (but that isn’t necessarily the case!). [VBScript has the `InStr` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for this:

```
str = "I came home at 10: 26 AM and made lunch."
position = InStr("10: 26 AM", str)
```

Maybe you want to ignore spaces in the input (or allow them in arbitrary places). In that case, you can insert `\s*` in the relevant places – this will match an arbitrary number of spaces (zero or more) at that place. Your amended expression would look as follows:

```
"10\s*:\s*26\s*AM"
```

Finally, maybe you want to ensure that the text doesn’t contain *anything else* but *just the time*. In that case, you can use the begin (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to ensure that the string is only matched if there is no other text around it:

```
"^\s*10\s*:\s*26\s*AM\s*$"
```

(But once again we allow the text to be preceded and followed by spaces. You may want to remove this if it’s not allowed.)

Comment: Do you really feel that this answer contributes to the site? It's pretty obviously *not* what the OP is looking for (even if it is humorously snarky).

Comment: @Sepster I sincerely think this is the answer OP was searching for. I have expanded my answer slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I wasn’t being humorously snarky, I *do* think this is what OP is looking for. He wouldn’t be the first who gets confused on the point that all strings are valid regular expressions that match themselves (modulo escaping).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - OK, I'll buy that, though I still doubt this is what the OP is after. (+1 for the expanded explanation)

Comment: @Sepster I’m serious, it wouldn’t be the first time this has come up here. I agree about the standard string search – I rationalised this away because some (search) tools *require* their input to be a regular expression but you’re right.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I was thinking the same thing - perhaps [tag:qtp] requires regexes to perform validation?

Comment: @Sepster Never bow to superior rep. ;-) See how my answer has improved due to being called out.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair call.  Although I think when rep is not only superior, but _orders of magnitude_ superior... I'll bow every time :-)

Answer (score 2):

To match given time format (10: 26 AM) you can use:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])(: [0-5]\d) (AM|PM)
```

Fyi, it has whitespace after colon...

Comment: +1.  Looks like what the OP wants to me.